# Firebase serve does not update Service Worker

Tags: firebase, web-hosting, service-worker, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools

When I do a `firebase init` at command line, and create a standard web page, then a `firebase serve`, then open http://localhost:5000. I usually get a web page that I was working on at previous time. I am almost certain this is from a previous version of `serviceworker.js`.

Also depends on which browser I am using on my Mac (Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera), they will get different results. My feeling is that there should be a `ServiceWorker.js` clear or reset command so that a new `serviceworker.js` will be created.  So Question, is there a SW reset command someplace. Ideally at the command line?

Or am I just nuts?

Comment: I usually go to `chrome://serviceworker-internals/`, stop/unregister the relevant service worker from there, and then reload the page.

Comment: I did not know this... but on Safari, Preferences, Advanced Tab, at the bottom, there is a check to show "Develop" in the menu screen.  Do that and you have options to clear cache.  After doing this, resolved my problem.  My changes in Polymer code start to show up.  Still need to chrome, Firefox and Opera.

Comment: Cool. I didn't know that either. Thanks for sharing! You might want to provide it as a self-answer too.

Comment: Its not 100% answered yet...  There are still some strange things happening with other Browsers.   Polymer serve  vs Firebase serve...   A lot more to the story.

Answer (score 2):

Since the Service Worker registration lives entirely within the browser, there's no way for the `firebase serve` command to know that you've made changes.

To clear all local stored data including Service Worker registrations (for Chrome at least), you can open the web inspector, go to the "Application" tab, and click the "Clear site data" button. Safari does not yet support Service Worker, so you shouldn't see the same behavior there.

If you're working on multiple web apps at the same time, you might want to consider using different ports for each, e.g. `firebase serve -p 5001` for a second app.